# check if MKMarkerAnnotationView is cluttered or decluttered in MKMapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have done Clustering for Points by referencing the below example provided by apple. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering

I wanted to know wether there is any method which gets called when the annotations are cluttered & decluttered.

Or

How I can come to know that particular annotation is cluttered and decluttered as I need to run some code block for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can come to know that particular annotation is cluttered and decluttered.

Check within `MKClusterAnnotation.memberAnnotations` if a `MKAnnotation` is present, like so:

```
func isCluttered(annotation: MKAnnotation) -> Bool {
    let clusters = mapView.annotations.filter({ $0 is MKClusterAnnotation }) as! [MKClusterAnnotation]
    for cluster in clusters {
        if cluster.memberAnnotations.first(where: { $0 === annotation }) != nil {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**Usage:** picks a random annotation from mapView

```
let annotations = mapView.annotations.filter { $0 is Cycle }
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(annotations.count)))
if (isCluttered(annotation: annotations[randomIndex])) {
    print("Cluttered")
} else {
    print("Not cluttered")
    mapView.selectAnnotation(annotations[randomIndex], animated: true)
}
```

> check if `MKMarkerAnnotationView` is cluttered or decluttered in `MKMapView`

`MKMarkerAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`, and you can override `setSelected(_:animated:)`, for an example open `ClusterAnnotationView.swift` from your linked sample code and paste this:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation
    print("\(selected ? "Selecting" : "Deselected") Clustered Annotation \(cluster?.memberAnnotations.count ?? -1)")
}
```

Similarly you can override the `setSelected(_:animated:)` method in each `MKMarkerAnnotationView` in `CycleAnnotationView.swift`, paste in all 3 classes:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    print("\(selected ? "Selecting" : "Deselected") unclustered annotation with type: \(clusteringIdentifier!)")
}
```

Now run and tap annotations on map and check Debug area for print messages.